# How can I detect a change to an entity's EntityState?

Tags: breeze

I want to put a "Delete" button and a "Cancel" button on each row of a list of Customers. The "Cancel" button is disabled when a customer is "Unchanged". But when a customer transitions to a changed state ("Added", "Modified", "Deleted"), I want to enable the "Cancel" button so the user can reverse the changes -- whatever they are -- before saving.

I can almost do this by subscribing to `customer.entityAspect.propertyChanged`. A property change signals a potential change in the `EntityState`. I can subscribe to that event and have my handler update an `isChanged` observable that I've added to my Customer entities. Then I bind the "Cancel" button enable to the `isChanged` and I'm good to go.

But the `propertyChanged` event is only raised when a *data property* changes, e.g., `customer.Name("New Co.");`. It isn't raised when the user clicks the "Delete" button. "Delete" triggers `customer.entityAspect.setDelete();` which doesn't touch a data property; it simply changes the customer's `EntityState`.

(1) Why doesn't a change to the customer's `EntityState` raise `propertyChanged` and (2) how can I listen for a change to the `EntityState` so I can control the "Cancel" button?

P.S.: I'm using Knockout.

P.P.S: This question was inspired by a previous SO question ["*entityAspect.setDeleted doesn't fire the subscribed propertyChanged event*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281856/entityaspect-setdeleted-doesnt-fire-the-subscribed-propertychanged-event/14291778#14291778).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct that Breeze does not raise `propertyChanged` whent the `EntityState` changes. Maybe it should. We will consider that.

Nor does Breeze have a separate event **on the entity** - no `entityStateChanged` event - to notify you when the `EntityState` changes. We've considered that several times. We keep talking ourselves out of it.

There is a perfectly good solution that performs better than a dedicated `entityStateChanged` event. Right now you'll have to code it yourself.

The trick is to listen to the `EntityManager`, not to the entity. You'll find one variant of this solution in the [**DocCode "Teach Tests"**](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/doccode) sample; look for "*can control custom ko entityState property via entityManager.entityChanged*" in the *entityTest.js* module.

I'll tweak that to fit your example. The essence of it is as follows:

1. Subscribe to the `entityManager.entityChanged` event; when it is raised **and** the cause is that an entity's `EntityState` changed, you update that entity's `isChanged` boolean KO observable (if that property exists).
2. Add the `isChanged` observable to entity types that should be watched in this way.

Here's an example of step #1: listening for state changes

```
// subscribe with handler watching for EntityState changes
addEntityStateChangeTracking(manager);

function addEntityStateChangeTracking(entityManager) {

    if (entityManager._entityStateChangeTrackingToken) { return; } // already tracking it

    // remember the change tracking subscription with a token; 
    // might unsubscribe with that token in future
    entityManager._entityStateChangeTrackingToken =
        entityManager.entityChanged.subscribe(entityChanged);

    var entityStateChangeAction = breeze.EntityAction.EntityStateChange;

    function entityChanged(changeArgs) {            
        if (changeArgs.entityAction === entityStateChangeAction) {
            var entity = changeArgs.entity;
            if (entity && entity.isChanged) { // entity has the observable
                var isUnchanged = entity.entityAspect.entityState.isUnchanged();
                entity.isChanged(!isUnchanged);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let's talk about step #2: adding the `isChanged` observable to the type. You seem to have tackled that one but I'm not sure how. Perhaps the best place to do add it to the type is in the [**type's initializer**](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities) so you can be sure the property will be there, whether the entity is created or materialized by a query. Here's an example:

```
var store = manager.metadataStore;

function customerInit(entity) {
    var isUnchanged = entity.entityAspect.entityState.isUnchanged();
    entity.isChanged = ko.observable(!isUnchanged);
}

store.registerEntityTypeCtor('Customer', null, customerInit);
```

This all seems like a lot of work. It would be easier if Breeze raised the `propertyChanged` event when the `EntityState` changes. We'll give that more consideration ... there may be some good counter arguments. Meanwhile, I think what you see here is the best approach.

Comment: We are disinclined to  add this to the propertyChangedEvent. In principle, it's about a change to a business object property, not an entity infrastructure property. We also want to encourage people to use the EntityManager.entityChange event which is less likely to lead to memory links. The net of it: unlikely to change the behavior of propertyChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

We found wrapping the breeze entity manager inside our own gives us nice flexibility that makes this challenge a walk in the park, especially with the hasChangesChanged event.

```
var EntityManager = (function () {
    function EntityManager(breezeEntityManager) {
        this.breezeEntityManager = breezeEntityManager;
        this.hasChanges = ko.observable(breezeEntityManager.hasChanges());

        // Subscribe with handler watching for EntityState changes
        this.addEntityStateChangeTracking(breezeEntityManager, this);
    }

    EntityManager.prototype.addEntityStateChangeTracking = function (bem, em) {
        if (this.entityStateTrackingToken != null) return;
        this.entityStateTrackingToken = bem.hasChangesChanged.subscribe(function (changeArgs) {
            em.hasChanges(changeArgs.hasChanges);
        });
    };
    return EntityManager;
})();
```

Then on your viewModels, expose the EntityManager.

```
var ViewModel = (function (_super) {
    __extends(ViewModel, _super);
    function ViewModel(typeName) {
        _super.call(this);
        this.type = entities.getType(typeName);
    }

    ViewModel.prototype.loadEntity = function (id) {
        this.entityManager = new breeze.EntityManager("MyManager");;
    };
    return ViewModel;
})(ViewModelBase);
exports.ViewModel = ViewModel;
```

Then in your Knockout UI:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-i18n="common.save" data-bind="click: save, enable: entityManager.hasChanges">
```