# Breezejs - why don't changes to non-scalar or complex data properties trigger change events?

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I'm using non-scalar and complex data properties in Breeze. They work fine, except that EntityChanged and PropertyChanged events aren't triggered when items are added or removed from the non-scalar property, or when properties are changed on the complex property.

How can I get notified when non-scalar or complex properties change?

```
manager.metadataStore.addEntityType({
    shortName: 'Thing',
    namespace: namespace,
    dataProperties: {
        id: {
            dataType: breeze.DataType.Guid,
            isPartOfKey: true
        },
        strings: {
            dataType: breeze.DataType.String,
            isScalar: false
        },
        object: {
            dataType: new breeze.ComplexType({
                shortName: 'Object',
                namespace: namespace,
                dataProperties: {
                    a: { dataType: breeze.DataType.String },
                    b: { dataType: breeze.DataType.String }
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes to instances of scalar data properties (i.e. primitives and complexType's) do raise change events on the parent entity. Changes to nonscalar data properties raise an "arrayChanged" event on the associated collection. 
See:

http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/%E2%86%88_complexArray_.html

and

http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/%E2%86%88_primitiveArray_.html#event_arrayChanged

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I only get events if I change the entire entity, that is thing.object = {}; if I change a property of the complex type, there's no event: thing.object.a = 'hello!' raises no event. For non-scalar data types, I know I can listen to the arrayChanged event, but doesn't that contravene the advice elsewhere to prefer the entityChanged event to avoid memory leaks? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14297983/1330257)

Comment: No, for a change to a property of a scalar complex type you should see a propertyChanged event fired on the parent.  See: http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityAspect.html#event_propertyChanged

Comment: I can't get it working. See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fAmCNgqFqq1LJjf5w0q9?p=preview - I get a single event when the scalar complex type is created, and then nothing. What am I doing wrong? If you change the text boxes, you get a single message saying the property 'obj' has changed, and then nothing.